# How to a encryption to a AWS RDS MySql database and how to access that encrypted database using SSL in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pymysql

I created a MySQL database instance on AWS RDS. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yElIA.png)

It is showing encrypted as true. I can access this database using PyMysql in Python but that doesn't requires any certificate . I want to add SSL certication requirements while accessing database.
How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [encryption in transit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) for your database. The process is explained in [aws docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-ssl-connection/).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of Encryption: **at-rest** and **in-transit** ( [more: understanding security when using cloud storage](https://www.osbplf.org/inpractice/understanding-security-when-using-cloud-storage/) ).

Because your screenshot shows ***encrypted as* true**, it means that the encryption **at-rest** requirement has been enforced.

For that reason it remains the second constraint to be enforced: **in-transit**, as [Marci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248823/marcin) says too. In order to encrypt the traffic, as you correctly expect, you need to provide a Key. Because those keys have to be managed (kept in a vault, secure), you have few options to use, as you probably already did, the [KMS to manage those keys](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-ssl-connection/) (or [Using SSL/TLS to encrypt a connection to a DB instance])[5](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html), or for [you to provide those keys](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/#enabling-one-way-tls-for-mariadb-clients-with-server-certificate-verification).

After you make these decisions, that involves who you trust to manage the secrets for your keys, you can follow any of the path.

From the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-ssl-connection/), to connect your MySQL/MariDB client:

> To launch the MySQL 5.7 client or later with RDS certificate, run a command similar to the following:

```
mysql -h myinstance.123456789012.rds-us-east-1.amazonaws.com -u testuser -p --ssl-ca=[full path]global-bundle.pem --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY
```

> To launch the MariaDB client with RDS certificate, run a command similar to the following:

```
mysql -h myinstance.123456789012.rds-us-east-1.amazonaws.com -u testuser -p --ssl-ca=[full path]global-bundle.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert
```

*If your question would be more specific, we could guide you with the exact path*.

Comment: I need encryption in transit. I also enabled SSL by running "ALTER USER 'encrypted_user'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;  " but I don't know what to do next. I have an SSL global certificate file(.pem) but I don't know how to use that.

Comment: added info how to use the `.pem` to connect